# kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

i am trying to implement heroku app ..now facing one of problem login .so i wanted to database of heroku by command of 
            F:\ROR\industryprime\industryprime>heroku pg:psql database -a industryprime

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0/lib/net/ssh/gateway.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/helpers/heroku_postgresql.rb:54:in `maybe_tunnel'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:149:in `psql'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:212:in `run'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:34:in `start'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'its showing
```

i am already trying 
gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1
but its displaying same error

Comment: You need to use older version of ruby, for example, 2.1.6

Comment: Suggest you to install and use any distro of linux instead of windows.

Comment: I am  doing this in windows can you tell me the solution in windows-->Pradeep

Comment: can u tell me what can i do?